# Maximization of Utility Function

Tags: optimization

> Kabir’s utility is $U(c,d,h) = 2c+5d-d2-2h$, where $d$ is the number
>   of hours per day that he spends driving around, $h$ is the number of
>   hours per day spent driving around by the other people in his home
>   town and $c$ is the amount of money he has left to spend on other
>   stuff besides petrol and auto repairs. Petrol and auto repairs cost
>   Rs.$50$ per hour of driving . All the people in Kabir’s home town have
>   the same tastes. If each citizen believes that his own driving will
>   not affect the amount of driving done by the others, they will all
>   drive $D1$ hours per day. If they all drive the same amount,they would
>   all be best off if each drove $D2$ hours per day, where
>
> (a) $D1=2$ and $D2=1$
>
> (b) $D1=D2=2$
>
> (c) $D1=4$ and $D2=2$
>
> (d) $D1=5$ and $D2=0$

I used the formula $$U=2(\bar{M}-50d)+5d-d^{2}-2h$$

and maximized w.r.t $d$ but it's giving an answer: $D1=\frac{5}{102}$

Any help will be appreited.

Answer (score -1):

petrol and auto repairs cost 0.5 (not 50). This means $U=2(M−0.5d)+5d−d^2−2h$ and maximization w.r.t "$d$" gives $D1=2$. The formula for $D2$ is $U=2(M−0.5d)+5d−d^2−2d$, where "$h$" is replaced by "$d$". Maximization gives $D2=1$. Both formulas assume the budget constraint $0.5d+c=M$.